# Set style of extended TreeViewItem based on an extended property value

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have extended the TreeViewItem class to allow me to store extra data within a tree view item. I would like to be able to set the style of the treeview item based on the value of one of the extended properties I have added.

So far I have:

```
namespace GX3GUIControls
{
    public class GX3TreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
    {

        public bool Archived { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}

<src:GX3ClientPlugin.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:GX3TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Archived="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </src:GX3ClientPlugin.Resources>
```

But I get the error - Error 1   The property 'Archived' was not found in type 'DataTrigger

Answer (score 2):

DataTrigger has no Archived property, but you can bind your Achived-property to it via the Binding property like so `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Archived}" Value="True">`

To notify your view if the Achived property changes, you could either:

1.Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in your `GX3TreeViewItem`-class: `public class GX3TreeViewItem : TreeViewItem, INotifyPropertyChanged`, create a method which raises the PropertyChanged Event:

```
private void PropertyChanged(string prop)
{
   if( PropertyChanged != null )
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop);
   }
}
```

and place this method in the setter of your property:

```
private bool _achived;
public bool Achived
{
   get
   {
      return _achived;
   }
   set
   {
      _achived = value;
      PropertyChanged("Achived");
   }
}
```

2.Or make your property a [`DependencyProperty`](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it seems like you're doing it wrong.  Those properties should be on your data.

You can do something like this,

```
Style="{Binding Path=Archived, Converter={StaticResource GetStyle}}"
```

GetStyle is an IValueConverter, no need to extend TreeView imo.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to implement this. you should take a look at the [MVVM Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).

Your UI is not the proper place to "store extra data". UI is UI and data is data. This is the worst mistake done by people coming from a winforms or otherwise non-WPF background, using a wrong approach and a wrong mindset in WPF.

This will either not work (because the `ItemContainerGenerator` of the `TreeView` knows nothing about your class, or require extra work in overriding the default behavior of such class.